# Python could not be properly initialized

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyscripter

I have already installed Python. But when I open PyScripter. I am getting error. It says:

> "Python could not be properly initialized"

I'm using Windows 7 & (desktop). I downloaded Python 2.7.3 Windows Installer from python.org. should I download another version of Python.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same builds (both 64 bit or both 32 bit) of both PyScripter and Python?

Comment: i have used Python-3.4.2 version.command line 32 bit version @Selcuk

Comment: Are you sure that versions of Python and pyscripter are the latest ones?

Comment: i am using pyscripter -v2.5.3 and i have use python-3.4.2 version 32 bit command line

Answer (score 1):

I also went through the same problem when I first tried installing Pyscripter and Python(Windows 7).....It was only after several unsuccessful attempts finally have I installed it..!

1)First check whether your system supports 32 or 64 bit OS. If 32 or 64 I suggest you to download 32 bit python and pyscripter from the respective sites..

2)Go for **Python 2.7.9 and pyscripter 2.5.3** .Then,Remember first install python and then Pyscripter!

3)Now your pyscripter will be installed successfully!

4)Incase U want to install packages like numpy,scipy etc go for the command prompt and use pip command to install packages..

For further details [Numpy package for "python 2.7.8 and pyscripter 2.5.3" (64 bit windows 7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28893248/numpy-package-for-python-2-7-8-and-pyscripter-2-5-3-64-bit-windows-7)

I suggest to uninstall al your so far installed python and pyscripters before trying these steps mentioned... Hope this solves your problem..:)

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem myself.  Turns out for me it was an issue with 32/64 version mismatch.  I had installed a 32 bit version of Python on Windows 8 (64 bit).  I then tried installing 64 bit Pyscripter and got this error message.  Uninstalled both python and pyscripter, and made sure I installed 64 bit version of python and then pyscripter, worked first time!