# Numpy package for "python 2.7.8 and pyscripter 2.5.3" (64 bit windows 7)

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, pyscripter

I have python 2.7.8 and pyscripter 2.5.3 (64 bits)installed on windows 7....Can anyone tell me which is the numpy package to download for my OS..I went through many sites and installed many numpy and python versions to work on my pyscripter resulting in only wastage of time and getting more confused by uninstalling each..I see that most of the sites give .exe (superpack) files for 32 bit.The same version and all works perfectly with 32 bit windows 8 os.. I saw .whl files for 64 on

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy

..I dont know what to do with it... I am stuck with this...

Please help.. and thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it installing numpy..All i did was to switch to 32 bit python and pyscripter .I installed python 2.7.9 version as it offers pip command so that installations will be more easy..

In Command prompt I set my path to python 27 and run

```
 pip install numpy
```

I was shown with the error.."unable to find vcvarsall.bat"

and so I downloaded VCForPython27.msi from http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=44266

Again run the pip command and numpy will be successfully installed..!

Incase there comes an error "Could not delete multiarray.pyd :Access denied "Just close your pyscripter or probably restart and then run the pip command..Hope this helps someone..